# How to get C++ destructors in an LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, llvm

The names of C++ class destructors will be demangled during compilation. For example, the name of a destructor of a class `student` will be compiled to something like `_ZN7studentD2Ev`. So I don't know the exact names of class destructors. I'd like to do some analysis and transformation on destructors.
Is there a way to get all the class destructors of a C++ program in an LLVM IR pass (or Machine Pass)?

Answer (score 3):

I found that `llvm/Demangle/Demangle.h` may be helpful.

Here is an example of the demangler.

```cpp
  ItaniumPartialDemangler Demangler; 
  Demangler.partialDemangle(F.getName().str().c_str());
  if (Demangler.isCtorOrDtor()){
    outs() << MF.getName() << " is constructor or destructor !\n";
  }
```

There are ways to demangle a C++ function name, which may help us to identify class constructors.

Linux provides ABI to demangle function names

```c
#include <cxxabi.h>
char buffer[1024] = {0};
size_t size = sizeof(buffer);
int status;
char *ret;
ret = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, buffer, &size, &status);
```

LLVM has a command-line tool [llvm-cxxfilt](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cxxfilt.html) to demangle function names

```bash
llvm-cxxfilt func_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to guess based on the name mangling.

According to the [C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html), names of destructors [encoded](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-special-ctor-dtor) using one of the following schemes:

- D0 deleting destructor
- D1 complete object destructor
- D2 base object destructor

Then follows [function type](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangle.function-type), which in the case of destructors is `Ev`.

This may work for you, but be aware that it is not a cross-platform solution.

There could be a better, proper solution for your question, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the hack. Do you know how to get the list of all classes in LLVM? To apply your method, first I need to know all class names.

Comment: I think you do not need all the class names: IIRC, types at LLVM level are not connected with any functions. You can simply iterate over all the functions in all the modules and check whether the name matches this 'predicate'.